# c++ how to assign a pointer to a parent in a binary tree

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree, parent

i'm confused on how you initialize the m_parent to point to the node above the child.

```
    class Node
{
public:
    Node(string city);
    ~Node();
    string m_city;
    int m_parent_distance;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;
    Node *m_parent;
};
Node *m_root;
//void test_print(string target, Node *cur_root);
Node * find_node(Node *m_root, string target);
```

this is the node constructor

```
    Stree::Node::Node(string city)
{
    m_city = city;
    m_left = NULL;
    m_right = NULL;
    //what do i do with m_parent??
    m_parent_distance = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parent as a parameter to your constructor, and initialize it from there:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(string city, Node *parent);
    ~Node();
    string m_city;
    int m_parent_distance;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;
    Node *m_parent;
};

Stree::Node::Node(string city, Node *parent)
    : m_city(city),
      m_left(NULL),
      m_right(NULL),
      m_parent(parent),
      m_parent_distance(0)
{
}
```

By the way, you should use an initializer list (like I wrote above) rather than assignments in the constructor (like the code you showed us).

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou, this allowed me to wrap my mind around the fact that i can initialize m_parent when making the node itself.  ie   m_root->m_left = new Node(city2, m_root);  where you can easily see that m_root becomes the parent!

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way might be to add a method `AddChild(Node * child, bool left)` and call that on the parent. This would need to:

- Set `m_parent` in the child.
- Set `m_left` or `m_right` in the parent.

The alternative may be to add a `parent` and `left` parameter to the child constructor and do those operations there.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you would need to either add a function to add a child to a node, setting the child's parent pointer and the parent's left or right pointer at the same time, or create a constructor that sets the parent explicitly.

This is reinventing the wheel, however.  Unless this is for a school assignment which prohibits the use of the standard library, you should probably be using [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).